# I have this error: struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes when trying to decode a .wav file

Tags: python, wav, bytebuffer

Basically what I'm trying to do is get information about the .wav file and output it so i found this Stack Overflow question and followed the second most popular post because it seemed to be what i wanted however, I am getting this error:

- data = struct.unpack("f", "a".encode("ascii"))
  struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

when running the program.

Here is the code:

````
wavefile = wave.open('music.wav', 'r')

length = wavefile.getnframes()
for i in range(0, length):
    wavedata = wavefile.readframes(1)
    data = struct.unpack("f", "a".encode("ascii"))
    #data = struct.unpack("<h", wavedata)
    print(int(data[0]))```
````

Comment: `struct.unpack('f', something)` would unpack `something` into a `float`, and expects 4 bytes. However, `"a".encode("ascii")` encodes the character `'a'` using ASCII encoding, which means it will be a single byte. If you used `'utf16'` as the encoding, it would "work", although it would make no sense - what are you trying to achieve on that line?